# Is it possible to import excel data into laravel REST API?

Tags: laravel

I don't know how to import the excel data to my database via REST API in laravel, I try so much research on google but those tutorials and videos aren't related to API..... pls help

Comment: You are asking how to do it "via REST API" and complain that resources you have found  "are related to API"? Do you simply need to import excel data in to your database one time?

Comment: sry I'm the typo "aren't related to API". Yes I need to import excel data into my database by using API.

Comment: google: "laravel upload file via api". Then
https://laravel-excel.com/ - to read excel

Comment: ok, thanks for providing the link. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

**Download the dependecy using composer for Import and export excel file.**

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

**Add providers and aliases in config/app.php**

```
    'providers' => [
        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        ......,
        ......,
        Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
]
'aliases' => [
    .......,
    -------,
    'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
]
```

**Now publish the changes using vendor:publish**

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

***Make migration and migrate it using command.
Add routes**
**Create Import and Export class using import/export command
Note: This command avaialble only if you download dependecy successfully using composer(step 1)***

**In app/Imports/BulkImport.php file**

```
    <?php
namespace App\Imports;
use App\Bulk;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
class BulkImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Bulk([
            'name'     => $row['name'],//fields from excel
            'email'    => $row['email'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Make A controller and in controller use**

```
Excel::import(new BulkImport,request()->file('file'));
```

*Bulk is the model in this example*

Hope it Will helps Have a Good Day

Comment: Thanks, this really helps me. I've tried this method just now and overcome the issue already. Thanks a lot, have a great day for you